# clearcase - Error while creating a view

Tags: configuration, clearcase

I am getting the below error while i am trying to create view :

```
CRMSV3062: Problems performing setcs.


CCRC WAN Server: Error: Syntax error on line 2, near column 2, file "/var/tmp/ccrctemp/tmp21436".
CCRC WAN Server: Error: Config spec parsing failed: "/var/tmp/ccrctemp/tmp21436".
```

My config spec is :

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element  * .../CCR_PPD_LINEITEM/LATEST
element  *  .../ccrportal/LATEST -mkbranch CCR_PPD_LINEITEM
element * /main/LATEST  -mkbranch ccrportal
```

Comment: Second, make sure you don't have conflicting eol characters (mix of \r\n and \n). And that the three dots '...' are 3 actual dots characters (and not an ellipsis character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)

Comment: Other than that, it seems a fairly standard config spec: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm

Comment: Thanks.. but no it didnt resolve the issue.. any other suggestions.. I am working on desktop..its working on laptops..

Comment: Yes: try and simplify your config spec on the desktop where it is not working. keep only `element * CHECKEDOUT` and `element * /main/LATEST`. Then try and add back your other lines, to see what triggers the error.

Comment: ok thanks..i will try doing that

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on desktop... it is working on laptops.

Check your difference in term of:

- user rights (what is your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` on both machines?)
- view protection (check what returns `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`, in both machines)

Try with a simple config spec on the desktop:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * /main/LATEST
```

Make sure that config spec at least can be set.

Then work your way back to your intended config spec, by added bits to it, up until you determine what exact part of that target makes the `setcs` fail.